# Select calendar button using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, button, primefaces, calendar

I'm trying to select a calendar button. Here is my code:

```
driver.findElement(
   By.className("ui-datepicker-trigger ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only")
).click();
```

[image: Primefaces Calendar with Button]

[image: Html code]

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: i tried using className but here i couldn't able to get my id.can anyone suggest me to select the calendar button using xpath?

Comment: how to select a calendar button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `Selenium` **does not support compound class** to locate an element using `By.className()`, you should try using `By.cssSelector()` instead as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.ui-datepicker-trigger.ui-button[aria-label='Show Calendar']")).click();
```

Comment: can you tell me how you are selecting the css in above html tag?

Comment: can i get a answer for the below tah with same class and css value?

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand what are you asking?? Do you want to know how to prepare cssSelector to locate an element??

Comment: i need to select a one more calendar button in the same page, It contains same class name and tag name. how do i select a one more calendar button if the value of the both the tag and class is same?

Comment: @Naveen Actually this is an another question, you need to ask another question regarding this, Thanks

Comment: i posted another question!!can you check and tel me..thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.ui-datepicker-trigger.ui-button[aria-label='Show Calendar']")).click();
```

[second calendar tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcJj4.png)

Comment: This is the same code as in the answer above... Why did you post this?